# How can I apply CSS selector for multiple divs like block-11, block-12 etc?

Tags: html, css

I've multiple block IDs as follows:

```
<div id="block-11">content Here</div>
<div id="block-12">content Here</div>
<div id="block-13">content Here</div>
<div id="block-14">content Here</div>
<div id="block-15">content Here</div>
```

Is it possible to use **#block-[n]** like this for styling my those block?

Comment: I think this may fulfill your needs: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: You can use regex to select all elements with `id` that starts with *block* using `div[id^='block'] { property: value; }`

Comment: Do you also want to check if the value that ends with is a number or not?

Answer (score 1):

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

> [attr^=value] Represents elements with an attribute name of attr whose value is prefixed (preceded) by value

```css
div[id^=block-] {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div id="block-11">content Here</div>
<div id="block-12">content Here</div>
<div id="block-13">content Here</div>
<div id="block-14">content Here</div>
<div id="block-15">content Here</div>
```

Comment: It might - for completeness' sake - be worth explaining the difference between `[attr^=value]` and `[attr*=value]`, just in case multiple classes are used.